# How to remove scale/incrustation in bathroom

Tags: cleaning, bathroom

How can I remove incrustation which appears from the water in the bathroom floor (covered with plates) and the toilet. This appears when water dries and the salts which are dissolved stay on the floor building a scale over time.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is probably about removing the calcium carbonate scale that is left behind when water evaporates. Although you can use abrasives to clean it, this mineral residue from "hard" water can be softened using a mild acid, such as lemon juice or vinegar. Once softened, it is much easier to remove.

Comment: Use vinegar to wet paper towels, you can stick them to the places affected. Keep wetting it and rubbing. Repeat and rinse.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a toilet cleaner to remove the incrustation in your bathroom with these easy steps. Why I use a toilet cleaner is that, it is far more effective than a bathroom cleaner. I do this on every Sunday so that it keeps the bathroom fresh and clean.

[image] [image]

Step 1: Just apply or pour the liquid over the encrusted plates

Step 2: Sprinkle water on the portions where you have applied the liquid and wait for about 5-10 minutes for the liquid to soak.

Step 3: Brush the portions and clean with water.

Make sure to wear gloves before doing this.

Comment: This is a fairly bad idea. Toilet cleaners are aggressive chemicals, which are hazardous (degassing) and bad for the environment and should only used in a reasonable amount. The usual incrustations in wet rooms are simple lime (calciumcarbonate) which are very easy to remove with the soft acids like lemon juice or vinegar. 
Also, toilet cleaner are MUCH (Speaking of factors above 1000) more expensive than the alternatives.

Comment: Hi Sempie what you said was right but, bathtubs are not commonly installed in indian houses except the luxury ones. As a result, yellowish color incrustation can be seen on the bathroom floor and needs to be cleaned over regular periods. Otherwise it becomes slippery and the color of the floor also changes.